# Using a larger image than container for better quality with css

Tags: css, image

I've noticed that when displaying small images with a scale of 1:1 they often look blocky. I can overcome the problem when using the `<img>` tag by using a larger scale image and setting the desired size with css.

But, I'd like to load my images with css with `background: url(...)`

When doing this if I set my element size to less than my image size then the image is only partially displayed, I can overcome this using `background-size` but I understand that this isn't very cross browser compliant?

Take a look here to see what i mean http://jsfiddle.net/uSqJW/

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this by `background-size` property but you need to remove that background position or make it 0px 0px from left and top respectively. This property will not be functional below IE9.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK background-size is the only way to set the size as there is no ratio option, but it is well supported - see http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts

This is a good article about the benefits and machanisms of loading higher resolution images http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/easy-high-dpi-images/